# Is it possible to have multiple variable selectors in Grafana?

Tags: grafana

I have created a Grafana graph panel that uses two variables: `host` and `ifAlias`. I would like to be able to select a second combination from the dashboard as seen below. How can I do this?[image: Grafana Mockup]

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Select a second host to show both hosts and a second ifAlias?

Comment: Thomas: On the left graph, display one set of host/ifAlias; on the right graph panel, display a different host/ifAlias combination.

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you think of. But it is possible with `Repeating Rows` where you can specify which variable to repeat the row. So you would have one or more panels grouped in rows, and the rows are repeated for the selected variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to enable multi select on the variables and then let the whole row repeat based on variable A and each graph repeat based on the variable B.

To illustrate the outcome of my suggestion see this image (though there is no data in the graphs because of the lack of it in my prometheus):

[image: grafana screenshot]

I created first a Row and configured it to be named "$container" and repeated for each "$container", then created the first graph in this row and set its name to be "$container - $interface" and be repeated for each "$interface".

Answer (score 1):

You are using [variables](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/) and they are defined on the dashboard level. Your requirement is to have them on the panel level. That's not possible out of the box. But you can still create (code) own panel with support for that.